# Problem in Displaying HTML Files' Icons in Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, icons

I have Windows 7 x64 (built 7600).
I just installed `Firefox 3.6` and I set it as my default browser, upon I've set that all of my HTML files were been without any icons!
Could you please guide me how I can fix HTML files' icons when FF3.6 is my default browser?
Thanks.

P.S: 
Whenever I set IE8 as my default browser the HTML files' icons were fixed.

Comment: Whenever this happens, I uninstall Firefox and reinstall it from an installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just installed Firefox 3.6 and am also seeing this behavior. I actually hadn't noticed until you brought it up, to be honest.

So what we're going to do is work with the registry, a la the instructions provided [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/change-file-type-icon-windows-7-and-vista/). Essentially we're going to force HTML files to display an appropriate file type icon. I will edit this answer with more details in a few minutes after testing the technique.

**UPDATE**

First off, that technique should work, and the keys you should be looking for are `HKEY_ROOT\.htm`, `HKEY_ROOT\.html` and `HKEY_ROOT\FirefoxHTML`.

However, I'm noticing that I already had `HKEY_ROOT\FirefoxHTML\DefaultIcon` configured, and even after configuring `HKEY_ROOT\.htm` and `HKEY_ROOT\.html` as well (all to use Firefox's executable icons), and rebooting, and manually rebuilding the icon cache, I still have blank icons.

I'm not forced to believe that the issue is with the Firefox executable itself. However, you may have better luck specifying a .ico file.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what fixed this annoying issue for me.
I'm on a Windows 7 64 bits, and I use Firefox as default browser.

1. open regedit from Win Menu\ Run
2. go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FirefoxHTML`.

   - That registry key will be different if you default to Chrome. In order to know which key to go to, check the predefined value in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.htm`
3. Within that `FirefoxHTML` (or equivalent one), under `ShellEx` key there should be an `IconHandler` key
4. Just rename that last one, e.g. prefix it with an hyphen (`-IconHandler`) so to disable the HTML icon *special* treatment and revert to default icon string value.

HTH

Comment: This worked also in Windows 10 (upgraded from Win7).

Comment: Mine has no IconHandler key :(

Comment: I had the same issue after uninstalling Office 2010 on Windowns 8. Deleting the `IconHandler` key worked.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox icon missing in Windows 7 x64: 
https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/forum/1/481472
"Peter" has a registry fix there

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, I've followed the link, but it doesn't work for me!

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

### This is how i fix this issue:

**Windows 7 x64 with Chrome 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

1. Open `regedit`
2. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\DefaultIcon`
3. Edit `Default`–in the right panel
4. Copy `chrome.exe` path:
   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"` and paste into `Default`
5. Click `OK`, then `Refresh/F5`
6. Voila!

*Hopefully this help!*